# Параллельные анимации JavaScript

Tags: анимация, javascript

Как реализовать анимацию на javascript, так чтобы например после привязке функции где реализован алгоритм анимирования ко всем HTML элементам, которые необходимо анимировать, анимация выполнялась параллельно (то есть вне зависимости для каждого элемента, от того анимируется ли сейчас какой-то элемент или нет)? Анимирую я средствами setInerval(); При каждом запуске изменяю значение некой переменной которая после станет значением некого CSS свойства,  мне не обязательна техническая реализация, а просто подход к решению и логика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я-бы сделал так, есть единый интервал-диспетчер

```
function AnimateDispatch (interval) {
    this.timer = 0;
    this.interval = interval;
    this.handler = [];
}
AnimateDispatch.prototype = {
    add: function (f) {
        if(this.handler.push(f) == 1) {
            this.start();
        }

    },
    start: function () {
        with (this) {
            timer = setInterval( iterate, interval );
        }
    },
    stop: function () {
        if (this.interval) {
            clearInterval(this.interval);
            this.interval = 0;
        }
    }
    iterate: function () {
        for (var i = 0, max_i = this.handler.length; i < max_i) {
            var f = this.handler.shift(), rc = false;

            try {
                rc = f();
            }
            catch (e) {}

            if (rc) {
                this.handler.push(f);
            }
        }
        if (this.handler.length == 0) {
            this.stop();
        }
    }
};
```

Дальше ты создаешь что-то подобное:

```
function widthSrink( e ) {
    return function () {
        var w = parseInt(e.style.width);

        w--;
        if (w > 0) {
            e.style.width = w + "%";
            return true;
        }
        else {
            e.style.display = "none";
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Ну а потом запускаешь "захлопывание" нескольких элементов одновременно:

```
var ad = AnimateDispatch( 10 ); // Это нужно делать один раз
ad.add(widthSrink(document.getElementById("id1")));
ad.add(widthSrink(document.getElementById("id2")));
ad.add(widthSrink(document.getElementById("id3")));
```

В общем как-то так получается... :-)

P.S. Скрипты написал только для показа принципа, в работоспособности не уверен.